# $stateParams are undefined after passing to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, undefined

I am using ui-router to pass an object to another state and controller using

```
$state.go()
```

But the console.log for the $stateParams object is showing up as undefined. The object is made up x and y coordinates which are simple integer values between 0 and 20. When I console.log the userData in the `EnterCtrl` I get the correct variables, so I presume the correct information is been sent.

I have looked through many examples on here and tried many options, but I can not get it to work. How can I get the `$stateParams` to be seen by the `CanvasCtrl`

`EnterCtrl` passes the userData object using `$state.go`

```
myMap.controller('EnterCtrl',['$scope', '$state', function EnterCtrl($scope,$state){
    $scope.formData = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var userData = $scope.formData;
   // console.log(userData);

    $scope.goToAnswer = function(){
        console.log(userData);
            $state.go('answer', {coor: userData})  ;
        };

}]);
```

Answer State which the object gets passed to.

```
var answerState = {
        name: 'answer',
        url: '/answer/:coor',
        templateUrl: 'partials/answer.html',
        controller: 'CanvasCtrl',
        params: {coor: null}
    };
```

The controller which recieves the stateParams.

```
myMap.controller('CanvasCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$stateParams',function CanvasCtrl($scope,$state,$stateParams){

var userData = $stateParams.coor;
    // var userDataY = $stateParams.coor.y;
    //var userDataX = $stateParams.coor.y;

   console.log(userData);
}]);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/lwP7DGkwHl2ZWWegazyv?p=preview

Comment: can you share the ui-router version ?

Comment: Can you add a plunker?

Comment: @clever_bassi I just added it there.

Comment: @puemos angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your issue [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cFWqp3XAidn8jjYFo09z?p=preview). 
Basically, I added `JSON.stringify` to convert the object to json before sending it otherwise it would print as `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thanks that worked and I can now see the data, when I print to console. When I pass the data to another method and try access the x and y variables I get undefined. Is that because the object was stringifyed?

Comment: or try using JSON.parse() to get the object from the string

Comment: I have updated the plunkr and I will try JSON.parse()

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

first create a factory which set your state param value contains function like below:

```
      function stateParam() { 
          var selectedRelease = "your value"
          $state.go('app.dashboard.detail.releases', {'selectedRelease': 
                    selectedRelease});
         }
```

inject this factory in both controller.

call this function in your first controller using factory name. Like if you have factory name than you can call it as:
**factory.stateParam()**

Comment: it should work without the factory, it's a workaround and not solving the original problem, just hiding it